# Comparing lists and values that exist in one and not the other

Tags: c#, .net

I am developing an MVC 5 Web Application - I have a screen where a user can tick checkboxes on a grid and this will save the data to the Database.  What I need to implement now is the removal of the data if the user navigated back to the screen and unchecked one of the items and then continued.

So the code in my controller so far looks as below:

```
IEnumerable<string> splitSelectedCars = model.SelectedCars
                                             .Split(',')
                                             .Select(sValue => sValue.Trim());

if (cars.Count > 0)
{
    IEnumerable<string> savedCarsInDb = cars.Select(c => c.Id).ToList();

    //var merged = splitSelectedCars.Union(savedCarsInDb ,)

    //puesdo code - for each value in merged call service layer to remove 

}
```

I am not sure if using a union is the best approach here to find all the values that are in the splitSelected cars list from the model that are not in the savedCarsInDb list and if so what the `IEqualityComparer` should look like?

So an example list the first time would be 1,2,3,4 passed in to the model - split out and then saved to DB.  If the User navigates back and deslects id 4 then splitSelected will have 1,2,3 and savedCarsInDb will still have 1,2,3,4 - so I need to find '4' and then call remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ can help you here, specificall [the Except method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var selected = model.SelectedCars.Split(',').Select(sValue => sValue.Trim());
var saved = cars.Select(c => c.Id).ToList();
var removed = saved.Except(selected);
```

Depending upon whether you wish casing to be sensitive or not you can pass in the appropriate string comparer:

```
var removed = saved.Except(selected, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Thanks rick - will give this a go - I guess I could use something similar to ensure Add is not called for a second Car that is already in the DB (i.e - currently - if a user navigates back the ids selected will get saved in the db twice)

Comment: @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat Set logic is the way to go for that particular problem. A HashSet (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) will do the trick.